# mysql syntax with array possibly need join?

Tags: php, mysql, json, join, pdo

I'm still fairly new to mysql and would like to ask for some help.

**users table**

```
idusers      name           other_info
1           Test Last          email
2           True Blue          phone
3           False Name         phone
4           Purpose Test       email
```

**likes table**

```
id          idusers         iditems
1             1                3
2             1                4
3             1                4
4             2                3
5             3                3 
6             2                1
```

Currently I have this table set up in mysql, and the idusers should match in my syntax to get information about that certain user that liked those certain items.

I currently have something like this

`$liked_users = $dbh->query("SELECT users.idusers,likes.idusers FROM users,likes WHERE users.idusers = likes.idusers");`

This should match up right?

But I'm trying to output some JSON array where this data of users should fall into certain iditems

```
    while($row = $items-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        //$get_liked_idusers = $liked_idusers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //$liked_users ->execute(array($get_liked_idusers));

    $json['data'][] = array(
    'id'=>$row['iditems'],
    "likes" => array(
    "data"=>$liked_users -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) //users should be displayed only if they liked the item that is going through this while loop only.
    )
    );
}
```

So I'm trying to output information regarding users inside the `"data"` array and it should follow the iditems. And I'm not sure how I would do so, because I don't think adding "`AND iditems = ?"` inside my first `$liked_users` mysql syntax will work as its asking to get two different tables.

I hope my question is clear?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$liked_users = $dbh->query("SELECT users.idusers,likes.idusers,likes.iditems FROM users,likes WHERE users.idusers = likes.idusers")
```

cause you query should have that many feilds that you want to loop through your json data

Comment: +1 for giving me a start, although its not the right syntax answer I was looking for, but I edited to have it correct